# Provide global information in a php application (secure way)

Tags: php, security, content-management-system

How is it possible to provide global information (paths, DB passwords, Timezone, ...) in a PHP Application? I know, that global variables are unsafe, but how do common CMS handle this problem? I already looked at Wordpress, but WP isn't famous for it's high security standards.

I've read a little bit about Dependency Injection, but is this the common way to handle this?

All in all I want to provide a type of global (but controlled*) information.

*Is it possible to control the provided data in a way that only authorized objects get the required information?

Comment: It's PHP... even if you wrapped the private information with appropriate objects, the stuff'd still be listed in file somewhere and can be parsed out easily, without ever actually executing the relevant PHP code.

Comment: @yes123: ^^Useless comment is useless. Provide a link and/or vote to close the question with a reference to the relevant answer.

Comment: Some zealous universal downvoting here - is this because the question is potentially duplicate?

Comment: @George: you right but on the Close pop-up there aren't any easy search functions so most of the time i just suggest it's duplicated.

Comment: @Decaon: acutally i downvoted 2 answers because they are not good answers (imo of course) and uppvoted the one with DI

Comment: The relevant data will be stored in an encrypted xml file and only the config class will be able to encode it. The config class itself is a singelton and the instance will be passed from instance to instance (if needed). And the config instance will test the "area" for permissions and return the requested data - this would be the idea, but is it overengineered? realizable? How can I receive information about the environment of an instance like the object who calls methods from this config instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use configuration files (.ini), it's easy to use with this PHP function  `parse_ini_file`.

You can use it like that :

config.ini

```
[global-information] 

path : your_path
DB_passwords : your_password
Timezone : your_timezone
```

In your php file you can get global information like that

```
$ini_array= parse_ini_file("config.ini",true);

$path = $ini_array['global-information']['path'];
```

Comment: I am looking for a way to handle and pass the variables between Objects/Files etc. (spread data) and not how to store them.

Comment: @NaN you can combine configuration file and Registry Design Pattern

Answer (score 1):

Dependency injection has nothing to do with security. It is a design pattern, a strategy to solve a common problem in a well-structure way.

I typically prepare a class CSettings, which provides method for all types of information, but all in a generic way by means of methods.

Then, when used in a specific application, I subclass CSettings in such a way, that it returns the correct / concrete values for the specific application.

Another way to promote information, could be e.g. the registry pattern.

Answer (score -1):

There are many schools of thought on this.  The most basic implementation is probably a global configuration file that sets constants using `define()`

I once worked with a framework that used this method extensively, coupled with singletons for Database Access and domain settings.  It is still widely used, but generally deeper dependency injection, where definitions for configuration are made class specific is now considered more modern and reusable, since the single package contains all the definitions to make it work in the same file.

http://misko.hevery.com/2009/01/14/when-to-use-dependency-injection/

This is a great article about the finer points of dependency injection.  The key thing to remember is that objects should only instantiate or hand off other objects if they are directly needed within the current scope.  The author gets in to great detail.

There are also alot of more famous libraries like HTMLPurifier that use a configuration object that gets handed to the constructor of the object instance when it is created.  This is a good approach if your object has highly complicated and nested config.

Comment: I don't want to use define because it's easy to loose track of our Configuration on bigger projects. Therefore I use xml or ini files to store the Information and a Object that handles the Infos. Now I am looking for a efficient way to pass the information between my project instances.